# Wordpress tries to get an archive of non-existing category

Tags: wordpress

In short, I'm moved some articles from default post-type to custom post type. And now, my articles are accessible using an old `www.example.com/articleurl/` and a new one `www.example.com/blog/articleurl/` urls.

There is a problem: a client added an article with url '2093'. And it's accessible using `www.example.com/blog/2093/`. But when I try to get it using `www.example.com/2093/` wordpress tries to get some archive of 2093 year or category(there is no such category, by the way) and then redirects to the index page.

So how to solve this?

No, I can't change url of this article. I need to leave it `2093`.

Yes, I need this hierarchy of my site and I need custom post type.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called archive-2093.php in your theme root and add the following code:

```
<?php

$args = array (
    'name'         => '2093',
    'post_type'    => array( 'blog' ),
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        //  adapt the following to suit the formatting and fields of your post.

        the_title();
        the_content();

    }
} else {
    // oh no, it didn't work.
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You'll have to adapt the loop to match whatever layout and structure you're using in single.php or blog-single.php. The concept here is to create a specific archive for the year 2093 and then just do a custom query to return your post.

Just remember to update your code in the year 2093.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress not serving the page over /2093 makes sense. Having the page on /blog/2093 AND on /2093 will count as duplicate content, which is not advised SEO wise. (Could be fixed with canonical tags)

The above solution suggests you use a new template file, which adds up in maintenance. My suggestion would be to simply add a redirect from /2093 to /blog/2092. This redirect should work before Wordpress tries to parse it as an archive. You could do this in your .htaccess file, yet I recommend using a redirect plugin. (Yoast has this included)

If the URL as /2093 is needed, just add this as a regular page instead of blog item.

Answer (score 0):

Viper007Bond created a plugin that may help with your issue.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-numeric-stubs/

Also, it would be helpful if you shared the permalink structure you're using.

Best of luck!